# Tried so many things regarding Django migrations issue but still I can,t fix this error?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Hey guys I'm getting an error with migrations from past two days.I added a new field into a model and then I tried to run `makemigratons` It worked fine but when I tried to `migrate` then I got a **datetime error**.After much effort i had to finally delete my database.And than It worked fine but when I try to migrate It now shows me

`return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_upload`

Even though I have a Upload model

```
here,s the models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from tinymce import HTMLField

from datetime import datetime

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = HTMLField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog',kwargs = {
            'pk':self.pk
            })

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all()




class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "comments")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField(default = True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self",on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name


    def children(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(parent = self)

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return False
        return True 


class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%M/%d/')
```

Here,s the migration that was created

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-02-27 13:37

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import tinymce.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('body', models.TextField(default=True)),
                ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('parent', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.Comment')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['-pub_date'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('body', tinymce.models.HTMLField()),
                ('published_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('featured', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('categories', models.ManyToManyField(to='app.Category')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Upload',
            fields=[
                ('image', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('file', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='post',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='comments', to='app.Post'),
        ),
    ]
```

Here,s the migration for uploads.py

## Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-02-28 06:22

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('app', '0002_auto_20190227_0541'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='upload',
        name='id',
        field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've deleted your database, therefore there's no such table.

Since you've deleted the database, you can also delete migration files and regenerate them.

Comment: Are you sure?
Deleted all the migration files including `0002_auto_20190227_0541`? Why is it in the dependencies then?

Comment: This is before I haven,t deleted the migrations

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not worry about existing data in database and just want to fix migrations and up and running**

- Check if your app is in

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ......
    'my_app',
    .....

]
```

- Delete Database
- Create Database
- Delete All the migrations files but not `__init__.py`
- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: let me if it helps. Probably you are forgetting to create database after deleting.

Comment: I did it but now I am not able to create supe user.It gives me an operational error

Comment: Do you have auth in INSTALLED_APP

Comment: yeah I have auth in installed apps

Comment: Do you have custom user model ?